# How do I use jquery's .html( ) in opal-jquery?

Tags: jquery, opalrb

I've read all of the documentation I can find and it is a bit spotty. Can someone tell me how to use jquery's `.html()` method in the `ruby -> jquery` bridge opal-jquery?
Also any advice for how I would go about figuring out implemented methods in a sparsely documented gem in the future would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `.html()` method in `opal-jquery` is mapped as `Element#html` and `Element#html=`.

The latter is definitively more like Ruby and is obviously there to set HTML content.

For convenience though you can still use `#html` as both a setter (with an argument) or a getter (no arguments).

This is where `.html()` is aliased as `#html=`:

https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery/blob/eab45e24ed1128721395d38d7d4b9e84c4427c00/opal/opal-jquery/element.rb#L78

This is where `#html` is defined:

https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery/blob/eab45e24ed1128721395d38d7d4b9e84c4427c00/opal/opal-jquery/element.rb#L214-L222